# Datatables: delete row on the client side

Tags: html, jquery, database, spring-boot, datatables

I have a SpringBoot application that uses datatables ,
here my datatable on the template

```
   <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Actions1</th>
                        <th>Actions2</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="pic: ${pics}" >
                        <td class="col_name" >
                            <div class="box small">
                                <img th:src="${pic}"/>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col_actions">
                            <a style="color:#808080; margin-right: 10px;">
                                <input type="radio" name="${pic}"  th:field="*{nadal}" th:value="${pic}" >Nadal<br>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td><button>Delete</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Actions1</th>
                        <th>Actions2</th>
                    </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
```

and the javascript code on the same page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
      searching: false,
      paging: false
    }).on("click", "button", function(){
      alert('deleting row');
      console.log($(this).parent());
      table.row($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw(false);
    });
  });
</script>
```

but When I click it makes a server submit of the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    const table = $('#example').DataTable({
      searching: false,
      paging: false
    }).on("click", "button", function () {
      alert('deleting row');
      console.log($(this).parent());
      table.row($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw(false);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do whatever you want regardless of the scenario in all programming languages is just create a variable and an if statement. create a Boolean variable in the start and set the value to false. Whenever you want to display something or not display it, just create an if statement saying

```
if(<name of variable>){
  display()
}else{
  dontDisplay()
}
```

You don't have to say `=== true`, you just need to give the variable's name since if you give the name it defaults to true, you only need to say `=== false` for an else if statement.

This works all the time and you can also eliminate false positives, negatives or double alerts in many cases.